# node: has no method create

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm trying to test out a node/backbone tutorial at this git hub site `$ git clone git://github.com/antoviaque/backbone-relational-tutorial.git`. When I start the node server (by running command `node app`), I'm getting an error that a method create doesn't exist in a restify module. The error's triggered right after the server appears to start

```
restify listening at http://0.0.0.0:3001
```

I'm not at all experienced with node, and would appreciate any help you can offer.

```
node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:724
        d = domain.create();

Object function Domain(options){
...lots of code ommitted....
    has no method 'create'
        at Server._run (/Users/mm/Sites/backboneforum/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:724:20)
        at onRoute (/Users/mm/Sites/backboneforum/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:592:38)
        at Router.find (/Users/mm/Sites/backboneforum/node_modules/restify/lib/router.js:372:17)
        at _route (/Users/mm/Sites/backboneforum/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:532:29)
        at Server._handle (/Users/mm/Sites/backboneforum/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:617:17)
        at Server.onRequest (/Users/mm/Sites/backboneforum/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:201:22)
        at Server.emit (events.js:70:17)
        at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1514:12)
        at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
        at Socket.ondata (http.js:1410:22)
```

Comment: Which version of Node.js are you running? Domains have been introduced in 0.8.x, so perhaps you have an older version installed? You can find out using `$ node --version` at the command prompt.

Comment: That seesm to have been a problem. I was using 0.6, but then I upgraded to latest .10 and got Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 1

Comment: Actually the package json file in the app says "node":">= 0.6.0 < 0.7.0". It's not expecting me to use 0.8x

Comment: Try adjusting this setting in package.json to a value that also accepts 0.8.x. Quite often this works as well.

Comment: I've put the comments into an answer. If this answers your question, it would be great if you could a) mark it as answer, and b) up-vote it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To put the comments into an answer:

It does not work, because the `domain` module was introduced as part of Node.js 0.8. As you are running 0.6, it can not be found. Hence you get an appropriate error message.

As you have said, your `package.json` says:

```
"node": ">= 0.6.0 < 0.7.0"
```

Try adjusting this setting to a value that also accepts Node.js 0.8 (or even 0.10), or - which may be the better solution - get rid of this line completely. If you do not use any things specific to Node.js 0.6, everything should still work.

Hope this helps.